# symfony 5.2 how to force using amphp client even if you have libcurl installed

Tags: symfony

Now Symfony support amphp http client ([docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#http-2-support)) if [amphp http client](https://amphp.org/http-client/) installed, but even if it's installed but you also have `libcurl` installed, it using curl client, but I need amphp one.

I tried to override configuration in the `services.yml` like this:

```
    Symfony\Component\HttpClient\AmpHttpClient:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpClient\AmpHttpClient
        arguments:
            - []
            - !abstract 'max host connections'
        calls:
            - setLogger: [ '@logger' ]
        tags:
            - { name : 'monolog.logger', channel : 'http_client'}
            - { name : 'http_client.client' }

    Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface: '@Symfony\Component\HttpClient\AmpHttpClient'
```

but it's not working, when I'm injecting `HttpClientInterface` Symfony still resolving it as `CurlHttpClient`

Any ideas on how I can force Symfony to use amphp client? thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there anything unclear about the documentation at https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#enabling-curl-support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this class: `Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient`. Its method `create` makes the decision about which class will instantiate and return.

The only way this method will return an `AmpHttpClient` intance is if CURL extension is not loaded.

With ini_set() you can choose which extension will load (I'm not sure).

PD. You can use AMPHP library, as standalone, visit https://amphp.org/http-client/